# Save selected items when using caliburn.micro /Telerik RadGridView /Silverlight

Tags: caliburn.micro, radgridview

I am using Caliburn micro(1.3)/MVVM and Silverlight. When I update the itemsource RadGridView, I lose the selected items. I found a blog about implementing a behavior to save the selected items when you are implementing MVVM. I can get the selected items, but I cannot set them back once the itemsource is refreshed. Can someoneshow me how to implement this using caliburn.micro and the RadGridVIew? I think the best way to go is to create a caliburn micro convention, but I can only find a reference for creating a convention for selectedItem, not selectedItems.

Can someone show me how to accomplish this? I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
  private static void SetRadGridSelecteditemsConventions()
    {
        ConventionManager
            .AddElementConvention<DataControl>(DataControl.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged")
            .ApplyBinding = (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
                                {
                                    ConventionManager.SetBinding(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention, DataControl.ItemsSourceProperty);

                                    if (ConventionManager.HasBinding(element, DataControl.SelectedItemProperty))
                                        return true;

                                    var index = path.LastIndexOf('.');
                                    index = index == -1 ? 0 : index + 1;
                                    var baseName = path.Substring(index);
                                    foreach (var selectionPath in
                                        from potentialName in ConventionManager.DerivePotentialSelectionNames(baseName)
                                        where viewModelType.GetProperty(potentialName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null
                                        select path.Replace(baseName, potentialName))
                                    {
                                        var binding = new Binding(selectionPath) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
                                        BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, DataControl.SelectedItemProperty, binding);
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                };
    }
```

Thanks,
Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a behavior for this since the SelectedItems property is readonly.
Telerik has an [example](http://blogs.telerik.com/vladimirenchev/posts/10-05-31/how-to-synchronize-your-ui-selected-items-with-your-data-context-using-mvvm-and-blend-behaviors-for-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx) for this, only the example is not specific for caliburn.micro.
If you add the following class to your project:

```
public class MultiSelectBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(MultiSelectBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));


    private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var collection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            collection.CollectionChanged += ((MultiSelectBehavior)target).ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeFromEvents();

        Transfer(SelectedItems as IList, AssociatedObject.SelectedItems);

        SubscribeToEvents();
    }

    void GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeFromEvents();

        Transfer(AssociatedObject.SelectedItems, SelectedItems as IList);

        SubscribeToEvents();
    }

    private void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;

        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void UnsubscribeFromEvents()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged -= GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;

        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            SelectedItems.CollectionChanged -= ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public static void Transfer(IList source, IList target)
    {
        if (source == null || target == null)
            return;

        target.Clear();

        foreach (var o in source)
        {
            target.Add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior takes care of the synchronization between collection RadGridView.SelectedItems and MultiSelectBehavior.SelectedItems.

Now we need to have an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel

```
    //Collection holding the selected items
    private ObservableCollection<object> selectedGridItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedGridItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectedGridItems == null)
                selectedGridItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

            return selectedGridItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedGridItems == value) return;
            selectedGridItems = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedGridItems);
        }
    }

    //Deselect all selected items in the gridview
    public void ClearSelectedGridItems()
    {
        SelectedGridItems.Clear();
    }
```

Last thing is bind the behavior in the view

```
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="CustomLogs" AutoGenerateColumns="true" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MultiSelectBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedGridItems}"/>                
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>                
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Thats it, hope it helps you!